# C# Write in a TextBox and preview in another

Tags: c#, string, textbox, preview

I'd like to ask the following question: when I write in a `TextBox`, I want the text that I write to automatically be written to another `TextBox` (like a preview of what I write).

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text
}
```

...But if the textBox2 contains text, the following code is a disaster:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text += textBox1.Text
}
```

How can I insert and delete one letter at a time?

Comment: If you want to do this without a postback you're going to need some Javascript!

Comment: @Liath: Only if they are using ASP .NET and not WinForms/WPF.

Comment: I've been in the web too long! I hope the OP will clarify.

Comment: I don't see any asp.net tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

And yes `textChanged` is useful for this and exactly what you needed.

Update:

Define a variable for store your static text in textBox2:

```
string staticText = textBox2.Text;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textBox2.Text = staticText + textBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: I had thought about this solution, but I thought it was too obvious :P anyway thank you so much :)

Comment: @user3105160 if this has worked please mark it as the solution

Comment: how come when I try delete a letter, add text too?

Comment: then you should store your current textBox1.Text lenght into a variable.But i don't understand your point exactly.Is there a static text in textbox2, and you want to append current text from textBox1 when text is changed ?

Comment: I have static text in textBox2. I want to add the text in textBox1, but this text is entered from the keyboard. When I add letters, the function works properly. When I try to delete letters by using the backspace key, the textBox2 is not updated correctly, that rather than remove them letters are added to the others.

Comment: try again, I have updated my answer.if there is a problem let me know

Comment: don't function :( e.Control is not part of the event `KeyEvent`

Comment: my mistake, it should be key down

Comment: the function works correctly, but I have problems with special characters

Comment: check again, i didn't try it that's why we getting unexpected results :D

Comment: Actually there is no need for all of this.A simple solution maybe store static text in a variable,and then you can use textChanged event, check again for last time :)

Comment: you're right :) this method works great ;) thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

This assumes that the other `TextBox` is named `textBox2` and that the first is named `textBox1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in WPF/XAML, you can use binding.

In your XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Text}" />
```

Comment: You can see from the event handler above that it's not WPF

Comment: See comments under OP re: question tagging/OP clarification. Nothing in the question that precludes WPF answers, and the OP's code is functional under WPF.